# Perimeter of an ellipse and some fun relations

Tags: geometry

It is well-known the perimeter of an ellipse can be computed by means of a **complete elliptic integral of the second kind**. That 
perimeter $p$ can be computed using convergent series as expressions of that complete elliptic integral of the second kind. For instance:

$$ 
p= 2 \pi a\left[1- \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2k^2 - \left(\frac{1 \times 3}{2 \times 4}\right)^2\frac{k^4}{3}- \left(\frac{1 \times 3  \times5}{2 \times 4 \times 6}\right)^2\frac{k^6}{5}- \text{...}\right]  $$

where $a$ is the semimajor axis, $k =\frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}$ is eccentricity, and $b$ is the semiminor axis. The question is: Can be proved or disproved that

$$
\left(2-\frac{p}{\pi a}\right ) \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1-k^2\right )^{\frac{n-1}{2}}=1
$$
?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Disproved: In your proposed equation, the series is geometric, with ratio
$$
\sqrt{1 - k^{2}} = \frac{b}{a}.
$$
The sum is an explicit algebraic function of $a$ and $b$. If your relation were true, the perimeter would be an explicit algebraic function of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Right, the sum is just $\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{1-k^2}}$.

Comment: Cool, So, $p=\pi a (1+\sqrt{1-k^2}$ is just an approximation formula to the perimeter of an ellipse, not an exact one. Thank you very much. Discussion closed.